# Why is simple JavaScript code not running?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Why is simple JavaScript code not running ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function(){
alert("Clicked");
};
    
</script>

</head>


<body>
    
    <a id="myBtn" href="#">click me </a>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `return false;` to the end of the function? And have you tried it on another browser? I have a feeling the alert's being blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your onclick handler after document is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function assignHandler() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    btn.onclick = function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    };
}

</script>

<body onload="assignHandler()">
<a id="myBtn" href="#">click me </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

the order

```
<a id="myBtn" href="#">click me </a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function(){
alert("Clicked");
};

</script>
```

Comment: This worked, but what if the script is assigned to external file and included in header ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents). The javascript block needs to be after the html element:

Your code works but is better to use like this:

```
var btn =
document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function
(e) {   alert('my click works after the html element has been created');
},true);
```