# Uncaught TypeError: second_input is null when executing a timer function

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

```js
var idinterval;
var second_input = document.getElementById("Seconds");
var minute_input = document.getElementById("Minutes");
var second_value = second_input.value;
var minute_value = minute_input.value;

var total = parseInt(minute_value * 60) + parseInt(second_value);


function starter() {
  if (total > 0) {
    total = total - 1;
    document.getElementById("timing").innerHTML = Math.floor(total / 60) + ":" + total % 60;
    return;
  }
}

function start_the_timer() {
  setInterval(() => {
    starter();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Starter {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(21, 27, 84);
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.Starter:hover {
  background-color: #0000B9;
}

.Pauser {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #767676;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.Pauser:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}

.Stopper {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.Stopper:hover {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timer.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Clockworks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 60px; color: black;font-weight: bold;">Clockworks</h1>
    <hr style="transform: rotate(90deg);margin-left:350px;width:200px ">
    <form id="timer_form">
      <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight:100; font-style: italic; margin-bottom: 500px;width:5px">
Minutes   <input id="Minutes" value="0" placeholder="00"   style="font-size:20px;background-color:transparent;margin-left: 10px; color:black;height:30px; width: 200px;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" type="number" min="1 " max="2000000">
  </label>
      <br><br>
      <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight:100; font-style: italic; margin-top: 100px ;">
    Seconds 
    <input id="Seconds" placeholder="00" value="0" style="font-size:20px;background-color:transparent;margin-left: 10px; color:black;height:30px; width: 200px;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" type="number" min="1 " max="2000000">
</label></form>
    <br>
    <button class="Starter" id="start" type="button" onclick="start_the_timer()">Start</button>

    <button class="Pauser" id="pause" type="button" onclick="stop()">Pause</button>


    <button class="Stopper" id="stop" type="button" onclick="reset()">Stop</button>
    <p id="timing" style="font-weight: 600;font-size:100px; position:relative; bottom:300px; left:500px;">00:00</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note: this is a simple function for a timer that gets the minutes and seconds from a user in an html input text** ,*this is the error shown in dev tools after executing the code*

can anyone tell me the cause of my problem?

> Uncaught TypeError: second_input is null

**Note: the problem is caused only in JavaScript code. I tried to change the value of minute_input and second_input to any int and it worked**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is simple javascript code not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092172/why-is-simple-javascript-code-not-running)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file is executed directly when the script tag is read, that mean before defining your Seconds input

3 way to solve that

1. Place your javascript tag at the end of your html file
2. Define your variables (those calling getElementById) in your starter function
3. create function containing all your code and call it when body is loaded `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the javacript code is excecuted before the input html rendered. Solved this by move those var to the function needed.

Comment: thanks for letting me know , i spent an hour thinking of the cause of this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are importing your javascript before you define your elements. When the javascript runs, the element with id `Seconds` does not exist (yet).

You can either move your script import to the bottom of the HTML page or do not look for the element until the start button is pressed. Move all the code before the `starter()` function into `start_the_timer()` function like below. Just make sure the `start_the_timer` and `starter` functions are referencing the same global total variable

```js
  var total = 0;

function starter() {
  if (total > 0) {
    total = total - 1;
    document.getElementById("timing").innerHTML = Math.floor(total / 60) + ":" + total % 60;
    return;
  }
}

function start_the_timer() {
  var idinterval;
  var second_input = document.getElementById("Seconds");
  var minute_input = document.getElementById("Minutes");
  var second_value = second_input.value;
  var minute_value = minute_input.value;

  total = parseInt(minute_value * 60) + parseInt(second_value);
  setInterval(() => {
    starter();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Starter {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(21, 27, 84);
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.Starter:hover {
  background-color: #0000B9;
}

.Pauser {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #767676;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.Pauser:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}

.Stopper {
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.Stopper:hover {
  background-color: #303030;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timer.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Clockworks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 60px; color: black;font-weight: bold;">Clockworks</h1>
    <hr style="transform: rotate(90deg);margin-left:350px;width:200px ">
    <form id="timer_form">
      <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight:100; font-style: italic; margin-bottom: 500px;width:5px">
    Minutes   <input id="Minutes" value="0" placeholder="00"   style="font-size:20px;background-color:transparent;margin-left: 10px; color:black;height:30px; width: 200px;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" type="number" min="1 " max="2000000">
      </label>
      <br><br>
      <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight:100; font-style: italic; margin-top: 100px ;">
        Seconds 
        <input id="Seconds" placeholder="00" value="0" style="font-size:20px;background-color:transparent;margin-left: 10px; color:black;height:30px; width: 200px;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" type="number" min="1 " max="2000000">
    </label></form>
    <br>
    <button class="Starter" id="start" type="button" onclick="start_the_timer()">Start</button>

    <button class="Pauser" id="pause" type="button" onclick="stop()">Pause</button>


    <button class="Stopper" id="stop" type="button" onclick="reset()">Stop</button>
    <p id="timing" style="font-weight: 600;font-size:100px; position:relative; bottom:300px; left:500px;">00:00</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```