# Why can I not open a URL in an iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Well, to put it simply, this doesn't work:

```
<script>
alert("You are about to send email to the client! Do you want to proceed?");
var frame = document.getElementById("iframeMailer");
frame.src="qr.php";
</script>
```

When the user presses okay, the source of the iframe does not load.

It is by the way defined as follows:

```
<iframe src="example.php" height=130 width=50% frameBorder="0" seamless name="iframeMailer" id="iframeMailer"></iframe>
```

Comment: Probably a ducplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mjcLozdw/1/ - works for me

Comment: Is your javascript at the top or bottom of the page? I would try putting it below the iframe in case the problem is on load the iframe has loaded yet but the javascript is already referencing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is simple javascript code not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092172/why-is-simple-javascript-code-not-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put javascript before tag "body"

```
<script>
alert("You are about to send email to the client! Do you want to proceed?");
var frame = document.getElementById("iframeMailer");
frame.src="qr.php";
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Use `confirm` instead of `alert` because `alert` cannot receive input from the user. Your code should be something like

```
<script>
    function queryFrame () {
        var frame = document.getElementById("iframeMailer");
        if (confirm("You are about to send email to the client! Do you want to proceed?")) {        
            frame.src="qr.php";
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", queryFrame())
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<iframe height=130 width=50% frameBorder="0" seamless name="iframeMailer" id="iframeMailer"></iframe>
```